# Siemens PG675 monitor problem

Tags: video, troubleshooting

I have been working on an old Siemens PG675 and suddenly the monitor began to show a a distorted image (it shows this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJnw7.jpg) when the should shows this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D82ZP.png)). I could make a test of the screen, and it shows this picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iFJI.jpg)

I have dissemble the device and visually there is not any disconnected or any burned element (resistor, cable, ...). On the monitor there are some references but I could not find any useful info [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrN6.jpg), I have also move the potentiometers of the screen but they only move or vary the screen view dimensions.

Edit: this is the picture of the PCB with the video chip [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbcsU.jpg)

Edit 2: this is the picture of the PCB with the DRAMs [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rSxy.jpg)

[image: wrong start image]

[image: right start image]

[image: test mage]

[image: PCB view]

[image: PCB with video chip]

[image: PCBs with DRAMs]

Comment: Most definitely _not_ within the analogue part. Looks rather like a memory / addressing issue. Somewhat like A6 is tied to ground.

Comment: I very much doubt the problem is with your monitor. I suspect the defect is in the device itself, its video output logic, its video memory or its mainboard. I could find little information about the PG 675 but I gather it's a PLC programmer.

Comment: There's some useful information about its sibling, the PG 685 [Here](https://forums.bannister.org/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=106592&page=all). Unfortunately many of the links do not work anymore. It's an interesting machine and it looks to be salvageable.

Comment: I have added a picture with the PCB where I think it is the video chip: MC6845

Comment: Most of the big ICs are socketed so they should be easily replaceable. It looks like RAM consists of just two 6116 SRAMs (2K bytes each). That’s not a lot. Otherwise I see no SRAM or DRAM on the board. The CPU looks to be a 8088. I would check the RAM and the 6845 first.

Comment: @Raffzahn Are you speaking about the UV-Eprom?

Comment: @StarCat I will try to find some replacements and make a test. On the other hand there is PCB with several HYB4164 chips (I will post a photo)

Comment: @Ucotecnico Picture 1 is quite clearly showing that the content of a line is repeated every 32 position. This means that either A6 (1 byte per character video RAM) or A7 (with 2 byte per character) does not change where it should. Usually this means the address pin is either tied to ground by some fault, or some address driver is dead. Of course it could as well be a problem with the character counter within the 6845, except that's rather rare - then again, this can be tested with the least effort by simply replacing the 6845 by a new one.

Comment: @Ucotecnico Well, true, it could be a programm error as well, as the load values of the 6845 registers are program controlled. A picture like above can be created by using 'wrong' values for line length and offset. But then again, having only these parameters screwed while the the whole boot PROM is basically working correct would be even more unusual. --- Long story short,it seams you cot a second machine (were Pic 2 was taken), so exchange the terminal board. If that is working, swap back and exchange single chips until it works again - starting with 6845, PROM and RAM.

Comment: @Raffzahn Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately picture 2 was taken from internet so at the moment I have not a donor

Comment: @Ucotecnico Well, then at least the 6845 and 6116 RAMs are pretty much available. Get some, try it. Where are you located (it's always helpful to add this to your profile).

Comment: If you need a load of replacement chips you cannot order anywhere, drop a list and I check my heap.